# How to describe polymorphic endpoint in Swagger?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, polymorphism, swagger

We use Spring+Jackson(Java). And in our API we can send a different object to the same endpoint.
For example

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
    include = As.PROPERTY, 
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")
})
public static class Animal {
}

@JsonTypeName("dog")
public static class Dog extends Animal {
    public double barkVolume;
}

@JsonTypeName("cat")
public static class Cat extends Animal {
    boolean likesCream;
    public int lives;
}

@Controller
public class MyController {

    //REST service
    @RequestMapping( value = "test")
    public  @ResponseBody String save(@RequestBody  Animal animal){
        System.out.println(animal.getClass());
        return success;
    }
}
```

Sending to `/test`

```
{
    "type": "dog",
    "barkVolume": 23.3
}
```

will show `Dog.class`

Sending to `/test`

```
{
    "type": "cat",
    "likesCream": true,
    "lives": 42
}
```

will show `Cat.class`

How to describe polymorphic endpoint in Swagger?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as you did. unfortunately swagger-ui doesn't support that right now.
You can see the discussions on github. They have opened several issues on that. While swagger still can not provide that feature. It did have a workaround for this, someone mentioned on github, maybe you can have a try.

> ringgelerch commented on Aug 10
>
> This is a very important feature for us as well. We use a workaround at the moment:
>
> For the GET method we define multiple responses like "200 Cat" and "200 Dog".
>   For PUT and POST we use different paths like "path/to/animals/animal (Cat)". To use the "try out" feature of swagger ui we created a PUT and POST with the valid path "path/to/animals/animal". To send a request just copy the body content from the Cat PUT or POST to the generic one.
>
> It would be greate to see the discriminator be supported very soon, because with upper workaround our api spec is hard to maintain and the rendered ui is not easy to read.

The links are here
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2438
or https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1526